# How could I configure WFQ on my own host?

Tags: configure, qos

I want to enable Weighted Fair Queuing (WFQ) when sending data on my own computer. but I only found out how to configure WFQ on the router and those commands are not available on my host. How can I use WFQ on the sender side?

I want to enable Weighted Fair Queuing (WFQ) when sending data on my own computer. but I only found out how to configure WFQ on the router and those commands are not available on my host. How can I use WFQ on the sender side?

I have found some commands to configure WFQ on router (such as system-view, qos wfq [ dscp | precedence ] [ queue-length max-queue-length | queue-number total-queue-number ]), but these commands are not available on my host (ubuntu 20.04 with kernel version 5.15.1).